# Using and if/else statement to output to screen or file

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am making a program for a class and have a virtual output function and an iterator that either outputs to screen with certain logic or outputs to file with certain logic. The problem I am running into is that it calls the IF part in the case where it should be calling the else. Wondering if someone could shed some light on this.

calling the Output function with :

```
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("save.txt");
    if (!fout.fail()){
        for (list<pethousedotcom*>::iterator it = homelist.begin(); it != homelist.end(); it++)
            (*it)->output(fout);     //<-- calling function below still calling the one that is only supposed to be for cout
```

Output function:

```
void bird::output(ostream& os) const {
    if (os == cout) {
            //still being executed
    }    
    else {
            // being skipped
    }
}
```

Anything obvious wrong here? or any advice?

Comment: Why on earth did you want different logic for different output sources? That's terrible.

Comment: I'm pretty new to coding and don't understand why its 'terrible'. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @MatthewEarly: In general, user expectations would be that any `ostream` they pass to that function would get treated identically. By having the explicit condition, it just breaks traditional expectations.

Answer (score 3):

> *"Anything obvious wrong here?"*

Supposed your file was opened successfully, the statement

```
if (os == cout) {
        //still being executed
}
```

just compares [the state (results of the `std::basic_ios::operator void*()`)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) of the both `std::ostream` instances, which is likely to evaluate to `true` for both of them.

> *"any advice?"*

If you want to distinguish that `os` actually equals `cout` you may compare their addresses:

```
if (&os == &cout) {
    // not being being executed when writing to std::cout
}
```

Comment: This should be from `operator void *()`, not `operator bool()`. The `explicit operator bool()` is supposed to fix things like this and turn them into error messages.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you're enjoying a defect in the C++ 1999 Standard. They wanted the ability to do things like:

```
if (os) { ... }
```

`os` would enter the condition when the `error_bit` hadn't been set yet. The problem is, the method they chose also let code like the following compile.

```
if (os == cout) { ... }
```

This code doesn't really do what anyone expects. It calls `operator void *()` on `os` and `cout`. So you're really just comparing if both ostreams have the error bit set, or if both of them don't have it set.

**Nobody** wanted that when they wrote that code.

So in C++ 2011, this has been fixed. We now have an `explicit operator bool()`. So we can still do this:

```
if (os) { ... }
```

But if we do this:

```
if (os == cout) { ... }
```

We'll actually get an error message. Clang reports something like:

```
foo.cc:10:17: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ofstream' (aka
      'basic_ofstream<char>') and 'ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>'))
    assert(os == std::cout);
           ~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~
```

To actually test if two references look at the same object, we should just compare their addresses. And that's what you're trying to do here.

```
if (&os == &cout) { ... }
```